# AttributeError: using Tweepy and Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to extract information from Twitter's API using Tweepy. 90% of the code works fine, but when I try to get the followers_count from each tweet, I run into an error.

The code I am using is:

```py
# Running only on handle returns a dataframe 
tweets = api.user_timeline(user_id=user_id, count=number_tweets, tweet_mode="extended")
print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets], columns= ["Text"])
data["Tweet length"] = np.array([len(tweet.full_text) for tweet in tweets])
data["Tweet ID"] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
data["Tweet Date"] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
data["Tweet source"] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
data["Tweet likes"] = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
data["Tweet retweets"] = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
# Line to be added here #
data = data.sort_values(by="Tweet Date", ascending = False)
```

When I got to add in the following line:

```py
data["User followers"] = np.array([tweet.followers_count for tweet in tweets])
```

The error message is:

> AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'followers_count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the first snippet refers to the `Tweet Object`, i.e. they all refer to an instance of a Tweet that you will be able to get the values from using the Attributes. You can see this by the name of the attributes.

On the second snippet

> data["User followers"] = np.array([tweet.followers_count for tweet in tweets])

This is not a Tweet object but instead a `User Object`. Therefore the dictionary that you refer to (`tweets`) will not have attributes with the name of `followers_count`.
You can see from the [documentation here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) that `Tweet object` does not contain any `followers_count` attribute.

In order to solve this, you need to make a request to get the `User Object`. You can see the documentation for that here - [User object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user)